# Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in library\Zend\View\Abstract.php on line 905 in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, htmlspecialchars

I am a very new in the zend world.
I have a form which is creating by extending `BaseApp_Form`. And obviously validation is also imposed on those fields. But after submitting the form, if it fires validation error then, along with the validation error message I am getting `Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in \library\Zend\View\Abstract.php on line 905`.
I understood that it is a problem for `escape($var)` function which is under `library/zend/view/abstract.php`. The values of $var are sometimes not null and sometime nothing. That is why `htmlspecialchars()` is not executing properly.
But now how to solve this issue.

UPDATED

```
public function init()
    {
         $validators=array(
                new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists(array(
                'table' => 'table_name',
                'field' => 'name'
        )),new Zend_Validate_Alnum(array('allowWhiteSpace'=>true)),new Zend_Validate_Regex(array('pattern' => '/^[a-z]/i')));


        $this->setMethod('post');

        $this->addElement('text','name',array(
            'label'=>'Name',
            'required'=>true,
            'filters'=>array('StringTrim')
        ));

        $this->getElement('name')->addValidators($validators);

        $this->addElement('textarea','textarea1',array(
            'label'=>'textarea11',
            'required'=>true,
            'filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
            'rows' => 5,
            'cols' => 50
        ));


        $this->addElement('textarea','textarea2',array(
            'label'=>'textarea22',
            'required'=>true,
            'filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
            'rows' => 5,
            'cols' => 50
        ));


       $this->addElement('textarea','textarea3',array(
            'label'=>'textarea33',
            'required'=>true,
            'filters'=>array('StringTrim'),
            'rows' => 5,
            'cols' => 50
        ));


        $this->addElement('checkbox','isApproved',array(
            'label'=>'Is Approved',
            'required' =>false
        ));

        $this->addElement('submit','saveCategory',array(
            'ignore'=>true,
            'label'=>'Save Category'
    )); 

    }
```

this is within a class which is extending `Zend_Form` and in the view page I am calling this form.

Comment: can you share some code where you get this error?

Comment: @Yogesh I think that is in codeigniter. But as I told I am very new in zend so could you please help in zend only?

Comment: @Mausumi The error clearly says that it requires string and you are passing array.